# Norwegian characters

Tags: php, character

I have the following PHP in my contact form.

```
// Ensure a message was entered, then sanitize it
if(!empty($_POST['cf_m']) && $_POST['cf_m']!='Enter Your Message Here')
{
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['cf_m']);
}
```

When I receive a message by email, the Norwegian characters, æ, ø, å become Ã¦, Ã¸, Ã¥.

What can I do in order to show the correct characters?

Comment: I already fought with this issue. If you want more information about what's going on, read here: http://forthescience.org/blog/2008/02/29/unraveling-unicode-problems-in-wikkawiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the encoding in the mail header, like it's explained in the php-comments on mail() (http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from) {
  $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
    . "\n" . 'From: Yourname <' . $from . ">\n";
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

It appears your form is served as `UTF-8`, but the e-mail is sent as `ISO-8859-1` (or another variety). You may want to explicitly set the character encoding of the sent e-mails by setting the `Content-type` header, for example:

```
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Set the `$additional_headers` parameter of the PHP [`mail()` function](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that those characters are UTF8 encoded so you can use the [utf8_decode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) to show them right

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8 throughout your code. For me, [this page](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8) was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is about sending an **email** with norwegian characters?
Take a look at [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), it's a great library for handling emails. Setting the message's charset is described at http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-charset. (And since utf-8 is SwiftMailer's default you don't have to do anything in your case.)